# Two factor authentication using Security token

Tags: apex, oauth2, login, security-token

I need to implement 2fatcor authentication but the requirement is to get login to envirnment using client provided Secrurity token(Hardware token).
    Once user entered username and security token from RSA ,he needs to be logged in to salesforce.
    I dont have any idea if that can be possible or not and how we can achieve it,If someone implemented this already.
    Any help much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Typically, I provide a full answer, but in this case, the actual documentation is worth reading directly, namely the [Login Flow Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm) page. The general summary is that you can create a custom Login Flow and use a TOTP (Time-Based One Time Password), which is actually given as an example in the document.

Comment: thanks,by this provided implementation can i able to login salesforce by Rsa token and pin set against this token.Please confirm as i am very much new here with this kind of work

Comment: @sudhanshu I believe so, but I have no experience in this, either. You'll need to do some additional research on this.